# Help me construct a list of best approaches for new C and C++ developers

Tags: c++, c

Not specific code writing practices. Please also include reasoning.

My start:

- use `GCC` or `Clang`

  - gcc because it is unchallenged in the amount of static checking it can do (both against standards and general errors)
  - clang cause it has such pretty and meaningful error messages
- when compiling C code using GCC use `-Wall -Wextra -Wwrite-strings -Werror`

  - in 99,99% the warning is a valid error
- when compiling C++ code using GCC use `-Wall -Wextra -Weffc++ -Werror`

  - you could skip `-Weffc++` (cause it can be confusing)
- always code against a standard C (C89, C99), C++ (C++98, C++0x)

  - while compilers change, standards don't, coding against a standard gives at least some level of assurance that the code will also compile in the next version of the compiler or even a different compiler/platform
- make sure that the compiler checks your code against standard (`-std=c99 -pedantic` for C99, `-std=ansi -pedantic` for C++98 in GCC)

  - cause automatic checking always good
- use `valgrind` or a similar tool to check for runtime errors (memory, threads, ...)

  - free bug catching
- never duplicate functionality of the standard libraries (if there is a bug in your compiler, make a temporary patch, wrapper, ...)

  - there is no chance that your code will be better then the code maintained by hundreds of people and tested by tenths of thousands
- make sure that you actually fix all bugs that are reported by automatic tools (GCC, valgrind)

  - the errors might not cause your program to crash now, but they will
- never follow recommendations that include "never use feature X"

  - such recommendations are usually outdated, exaggerated or oversimplified

Answer (score 7):

#### Learn C++ [from a book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/)

Unfortunately, most freely available C++ resources are complete garbage.

#### Use the ["Resource Acquisition Is Initialization" idiom (RAII)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization)

This takes care of 90% of your memory management problems. The other 10% can be taken care of with smart pointers (which themselves depend on RAII). Even though the language is not garbage-collected, I've never had to use a `delete` statement or some kind of `DestroyXXX()` or `ReleaseXXX()` or `CloseXXX()` function in application code - they're always somewhere deep in library/wrapper code.

It's the reason why `std::vector` allows for dynamic arrays without `new` or `delete` and `fstream` allows for manipulation of files without needing `fopen()` or `fclose()` in application code - it's all been taken care of.

#### Compile with aggressive optimization when you test

(e.g. GCC's `-O3` switch).  This will often uncover bugs arising from subtle things like violation of [strict aliasing rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule).  By doing so, you become aware of such issues, and your program will work properly in the presence of such optimizations.

#### Test on a PowerPC (or other big-endian machine) from time to time

Better yet, test on a 64-bit PowerPC if you can get your hands on one.  Things you can learn by doing so:

- When reading a binary file, you have to pack/unpack 16-bit, 32-bit, 64-bit, etc. words a byte at a time, or use some sort of endian-aware byte-swapping mechanism.
- `char` is not always signed.  On PowerPC Linux, GCC defaults to `unsigned char`.  This isn't an endianness issue, but it's a subtlety I picked up on while testing on both x86 and PowerPC.
- Big endian won't let you get away with `long n = ...; printf("%d", n);`
- 64-bit big endian won't let you get away with:

  ```
  curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 1);
  ```

  See if you can spot the bug.

#### Always pay attention to recommendations that say "never use feature X"

- Such recommendations are typically based on the experience of lots of skilled people over a significant period of time.
- If you choose to disregard such recommendations, make sure that you really understand them and the rationale behind them, before you disregard them.
- If you choose to ignore them out of hand, don't be surprised if people criticize your code.

Comment: There is such a thing as [a bad C++ book](http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/users/yechiel/CS/BadBooksC+C++.html) (e.g. anything by Herbert Schildt), and there are C++ online resources that are quite good (stuff by people who actually know what they're talking about, like GotW, C++ FAQ Lite, and of course Stack Overflow). But generally, you're right.

Comment: would you mind explaining more on what it does and why do you recommend it as answering the question asked? ["Link-only answers"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info "what's this") are not quite welcome at Stack Exchange

Comment: @gnat: You.. don't know what a book does?

Comment: (But, yes, this probably should have been a comment.)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit well since I didn't read it, I sure don't. That's why I ask to explain more, fair enough? _...if you are standing at 100 Main St. and you ask where 98 Main St. is... "I'll direct you to a tourism information booth, and they will be able to provide you with your answer and much more!"_